# Windows phone 8.1 stop accelerometer

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, accelerometer

i am developing an application for windows phone 8.1.

i have an if statement:

```
if(txtX.Text=="  .24"){

 accelerometer.Stop();
 MainPage.Score++;
 this.frame.Navigate(typeof(Final_Score));
 }
```

to explain the usage of this statement. I have it so the value of the X axis is placed within `txtX.Text`. Then when the X axis of the accelerometer is equal to 0.24 it increments 1 to score and navigates to another page. BUT the accelerometer is not stopping and is carrying to run on the next page. When i use the statement `accelerometer.Stop();`this is not recognised and states

```
'Windows.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer'does not contain a definition for 'Stop' and no extension 'Stop' accepting a first arguement of type'Windows.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can anyone help or provide the function to stop my accelerometer once the value 0.24 is met.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are working with is [`Windows.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer.aspx), this does not contain a `Stop`, you are probably looking at the  [Microsoft.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.sensors.accelerometer(v=vs.105).aspx) documentation (which does include a `Stop` method)

Instead of `Stop` just unregister from the Event

```cs
if(txtX.Text=="  .24"){
    accelerometer.ReadingChanged -= YourUpdateFunction;
    MainPage.Score++;
    this.frame.Navigate(typeof(Final_Score));
}
```

BTW, it is usually a good idea to unregister from all events when navigating away so that you do not duplicate registration to events when returning.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This makes more sense.